# Choosing collation for column in MySQL database when storing special charaters

Tags: java, mysql

currently I'm using mySql database, I used "Longtext" to store very large text (>4000 characters), I also set the collation to utf8_unicode_ci. I use java to read text from file then storing them to database . Since the text contains a lot of special characters, I used PreparedStatement in order to add texts to database.

But the problem is when I check data stored in the database, sometimes this weird thing occurs:

**Original text in file:**

Once parameters are varied, different forms can be produced.  These forms can either mimic pre-existing or model hypothetical possibilities.  These hypothetical possibilities or morphospaces lead us to the question of why these forms are not present in the fossil record.  Therefore these models can be the foundation of the study of the actual mechanism of evolution and the analysis of organic form.

One method for developing a model of shells is to create a formula to represent its trajectory of aperture movement.  In this study, we estimated the shape of the aperture to be an ellipse.  Coordinates of this ellipse were taken (center, horizontal and vertical radial distance.)  This data was collected and used in add-on software packages to Mathematica.

CerioShell (author: J. Stone) is an add-on to Mathematica 5.2.  An intermediate software package, Mappoint (author: G. Beck) bridges the two programs.  Mappoint uses both classical Euclidean and modern differential geometry to develop mathematical functions for graphing.  The utilization of these graphing functions to develop shell surfaces, whorl coiling and patterns of accretion/formation is the focus of CerioShell.  All products run in a Microsoft Windows environment.

**Stored text:**

Once parameters are varied,? ?different forms can be produced.  These forms can either mimic pre-existing or model hypothetical possibilities.  These hypothetical possibilities or morphospaces lead us to the question of why these forms are not present in the fossil record.  Therefore these models can be the foundation of the study of the actual mechanism of evolution and the analysis of organic form.

One method for developing a model of shells is to create a formula to represent its trajectory of aperture movement.  In this study,? ?we estimated the shape of the aperture to be an ellipse.  Coordinates of this ellipse were taken? (?center,? ?horizontal and vertical radial distance.?)  ?This data was collected and used in add-on software packages to Mathematica.

CerioShell? (?author:? ?J. Stone?) ?is an add-on to Mathematica? ?5.2.  An? ?intermediate software package,? ?Mappoint? (?author:? ?G. Beck?) ?bridges the two programs.  Mappoint uses both classical Euclidean and modern differential geometry to develop mathematical functions for graphing.  The utilization of these graphing functions to develop shell surfaces,? ?whorl coiling and patterns of accretion/formation is the focus of CerioShell.  All products run in a Microsoft Windows environment.

I don't know exaclty why this error occurs. Can someone show me what I did wrong?

Comment: You probably ought to be asking about character set, not collation. What MySQL client software did you use to display the erroneous text?

Comment: i've just tried with mysqlworkbench, it also has same problem ...

Comment: also happened to sequel pro